# Trouble with my "Like" system

Tags: cakephp, controller

So, I'm adding a "Like" system to my CakePHP project and I have a little problem. When I want to add a Like ... it simply doesn't happen. Here is what I have :

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->create("Like", array("url" => array("controller" => "likes", "action" => "like")));
  echo $this->Form->hidden("user_id",array(
    "value" => AuthComponent::user("id")
  ));
  echo $this->Form->hidden("post_id",array(
    "value" => $post["Post"]["id"]
  ));
  echo $this->Form->end();

  echo $this->Html->link(
    "<li><i class='icon-heart icon-large'></i> ".count($post["Like"])." likes</li>",
    "",
    array("escape" => false, "onclick" => "document.getElementById('LikeViewForm').submit();")
  );
?>
```

And here is the controller :

```
<?php class LikesController extends AppController{

  function like() {
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user("id");
    if(!$user_id){
      $this->redirect("/");
      die();
    }
    if ($this->request->is("post")) {
      $d = $this->request->data;         
      $d["Like"]["id"] = null;
      if($this->Like->save($d,true,array("post_id","user_id"))){
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And when I click the link, it refresh the page correctly, so I presume the form is send, but nothing new in the DB...

Any guess ?

Comment: You're calling the die() function before the save() method, did you know this? The die() function stops execution of the current script. http://php.net/die

Comment: Sorry, post edited, I was trying to find the problem, with some `debug()` , no `die()` in the clean code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new record, you need use `create()` first. Try this:

```
function like() {
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user("id");

    if (!$user_id) {
        $this->redirect("/");
        die();
    }

    if ($this->request->is("post")) {
        $this->Like->create();
        if ($this->Like->save($this->request->data, true, array("post_id", "user_id"))) {
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nop sorry :/ (btw, `create()` isn't totally required, for exemple, this other part of my project works perfectly https://gist.github.com/3800742 )

Comment: It is good form to use create() and if you get used to not using it, someday it will be back to bite your ass in the shape of a hard to track bug.